# Wireless networking on Ubuntu 14.04: Destination Host Unreacheable on LAN

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line

I've been having a weird issue where I can `ping` only specific pcs on my LAN but not others but I can connect effortlessly to the Internet.

the ping result for local addresses is:

```
   $ ping 192.168.1.10
   PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
   From 192.168.1.30 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
   From 192.168.1.30 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
   From 192.168.1.30 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable
   ^C
   --- 192.168.1.10 ping statistics ---
   13 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 12086ms
   pipe 3
```

My `ifconfig` result is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:cf:30:75:4c:c1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:748 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:486220 (486.2 KB)  TX bytes:134384 (134.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:258025 (258.0 KB)  TX bytes:258025 (258.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5d:60:5a:53:9c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.30  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4a5d:60ff:fe5a:539c/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2002:4f12:8714:e472:4a5d:60ff:fe5a:539c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2002:4f12:8714:e472:5108:36ff:308b:8c09/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10780 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5321624 (5.3 MB)  TX bytes:1502007 (1.5 MB)
```

and finally my `nmap` scan is:

```
$ nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-04-29 20:26 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0085s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.30
Host is up (0.00016s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.100
Host is up (0.073s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 16.07 seconds
```

I use this routinely to share file to my local NAS which isn't visible right now and for XBMC databases and I know that pings to other wireless clients work.

My `arp-scan` result is:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 192.168.1.0/24
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.1.1     44:94:fc:ea:f6:5e   (Unknown) 
192.168.1.100   cc:3a:61:e7:e4:91   (Unknown)

2 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 1.331 seconds (192.34 hosts/sec). 2 responded
```

Comment: I did some digging since noone is responding and I found that arp table shows the correct addresses for wlan devices but (incomplete) addresses for ethernet connected ones. Now my doubt is if this is caused by the pc or by the router itself.